# Script Windows FTP move and rename file

Tags: windows, file, ftp, move

basically i have a 2 files on my company FTP, i need the users to be able to click a script to swap the 2 files when they want.

FTP tree look like this:

```
/file1.vxml
/swap/file1.vxml
```

And here i need to connect to my ftp (on Windows), and rename /file1.vxml to /file2.vxml before moving then move it to /swap/ (to not overwrite /swap/file1.vxml). Then doing the opposite on /swap/file2.vxml and move it to the root.

i already have the connection :

```
open host.myhost.com
user myusername
mypassword
cd /
bye
```

but the thing i'm lacking is how to move and rename properly files on the ftp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "REN" to rename files in FTP.

```
ftp> REN FileA FileB
```

Renaming and moving are the same thing essentially in FTP, you can move a file to a different folder by renaming it.

```
ftp> REN Here ../There
```

You'll probably have to download the first file back to your local server to save a copy, then rename the second file, and copy the file you downloaded back up to the server afterwards. I don't know of any FTP servers that support copying files within themselves.

Comment: Thanks that helped me. As you suggested i added a line to download the file and upload it back after the rename.